# Script in gitlab-ci does not output errors

Tags: shell, gitlab-ci

I have a shell script that I use on gitlab CI that runs a supplied command. The issue is it doesn't display errors if the command failed, it just says `ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1`. I tried the script locally and it was able to output the failed command, is there a way I could somehow force it to display the error through my script before it exits the job?

The particular part of my script

```
output="$( (cd "$FOLDER"; eval "$@") 2>&1 )"
if [ "$output" ]; then
    echo -e "$output\n"
fi
```

Comment: Locally I am using bash since I am on ubuntu but on the CI, it's running on an alpine docker image so it's ash.

Comment: Hey glad to say that your suggestion lead me to a solution. This is what I came up with `output=$(cd "$FOLDER"; eval "$@") || code="$?"`. Then just did checks on `$code`. You should do the honors of posting an answer. I could also give you the working code snippet to put on the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to trap an error that works in *every* shell is to combine two commands with logical OR `||`.

**Catch error from subshell:**

```
output="$( (cd "$FOLDER"; eval "$@") 2>&1 )" || errorcode="$?"
```

will save the error code from the previous command if it fails.

**Exit with own error code if important command fails**

```
output="$( (cd "$FOLDER"; eval "$@") 2>&1 )" || exit 12
```

For more complex things one can define a function that will be called after the OR.

```
handle_error() {
# do stuff
}

output="$( (cd "$FOLDER"; eval "$@") 2>&1 )" || handle_error
```